# Upload image to strapi

Tags: javascript, strapi

I would like to upload an image to strapi with a html file. When I run the code, I obtain the error: POST http://localhost:1337/upload 500 (Internal Server Error).

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/upload',
    datatype: 'image/jpeg',
    data: JSON.stringify(img),
    complete: function(product) {
        console.log('Congrats, your product has been successfully created: ', product.description);
    },
    fail: function(error) {
        console.log('An error occurred:', error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

As I can see forgetting to add multipart/form-data

```
mimeType: "multipart/form-data"
```

You can see documentation [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/upload.html#upload-files)

1. Ensure that have send the request using multipart/form-data encoding
2. The parameters allowed are:

   ```
   files: The file(s) to upload. The value(s) can be a Buffer or Stream.

   path: (optional): The folder where the file(s) will be uploaded to (only supported on strapi-upload-aws-s3 now).

   refId: (optional): The ID of the entry which the file(s) will be linked to.

   ref: (optional): The name of the model which the file(s) will be linked to.

   source: (optional): The name of the plugin where the model is located.

   field: (optional): The field of the entry which the file(s) will be precisely linked to.
   ```

**Single file request**

```
curl -X POST -F 'files=@/path/to/pictures/file.jpg' http://localhost:1337/upload
```

**Linking files to an entry**

For example that you have link image field in User model named avatar

```
{
 "files": "...", // Buffer or stream of file(s)
 
 "path": "user/avatar", // Uploading folder of file(s).
 
 "refId": "5a993616b8e66660e8baf45c", // User's Id.
 
 "ref": "user", // Model name.
 
 "source": "users-permissions", // Plugin name.
 
 "field": "avatar" // Field name in the User model.
}
```

Comment: can you give an example using axios or request? I always get ` { statusCode: 400, error: 'Bad Request', message: 'Files are empty' }` when I already pass the file as buffer.

Comment: It's new api now, check new docs:
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/upload.html#upload-file-during-entry-creation

`formData.append('files.MODEL_FILE_FIELD_NAME', blob, filename)`

Answer (score 4):

As of today, you can upload a file to strapi using axios with the following code. This is the handler of the input event on a file input.

```js
onInput (files) {
  const axios = require('axios')

  const STRAPI_BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:1337'

  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('files', files)
  formData.append('ref', 'restaurant') // optional, you need it if you want to link the image to an entry
  formData.append('refId', 12345) // optional, you need it if you want to link the image to an entry
  formData.append('field', 'image') // optional, you need it if you want to link the image to an entry

  axios.post(`${STRAPI_BASE_URL}/upload`, formData)
}
```

I assume that you have a collection called `restaurant` with a field `image` of type file.

More on this here: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/upload.html#upload-files

Comment: I tried this code, but it did not work. When I changed formData.append('files', files) -> formData.append('files', files[0]) it worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: upload tells me 400 bad request, uploads gives me a 405 error.  Is that a standard route for uploads in stapi or is it set?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `RestRequest` in Winforms with C#:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://my-strapi-server:1337/upload");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddFile("files", @"C:\temp\bryan.jpg");
request.AddParameter("ref", "Singer");
request.AddParameter("refId", "605fe0c8sakhasg4c40253a");
request.AddParameter("field", "logo");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```