# Unable to POST file to /upload

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, strapi

I'm trying to upload a file. I've got it to the server and I can see it. The code I'm using to post is

```
postTheFileToStrapi2(file: File) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    console.log(file[0].name);
    formData.append('file', file[0]);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:1337/upload', formData)
      .subscribe((response) => console.log(response));
  }
```

The problem is, I get an error of:

```
{
"statusCode":400,
"error":"Bad Request",
"message":[
   {"messages":[
      {"id":"Upload.status.empty","message":"Files are empty"}
   ]}]}
```

But, looking at the headers in Chrome, I am sending this:

[image]

Any pointers would be greatly received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to replace

`formData.append('file', file[0]);`

with

`formData.append('files', file[0]);`

--> plural instead of singular. As far as I understand the strapi api (or upload plugin?) expects the data to be in a field named "files".

I struggled for hours until I read Pavlo Razumovskyi's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722625/upload-image-to-strapi/52693039):

> It's new api now, check new docs:
>   strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/…
>   formData.append('files.MODEL_FILE_FIELD_NAME', blob, filename)

That solved it for me at least!

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below example to upload image in Angular.

in your .HMTL file in your HTML file do like this

```
  <input class="hidden" type="file" (change)="readURL($event);" name="Uploadfile" 
   id="file" style="width: 100%;cursor: pointer;" #fileInput>
```

Declare fileInput variable like below in component.ts file

```
 @ViewChild('fileInput', { static: false }) fileInput: ElementRef;
```

you can try like this in component.ts

```
     uploadPhoto() {

       let userid = "43345;
      var nativeElement: HTMLInputElement = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
      var file = nativeElement.files[0];
      nativeElement.value = '';
      this.sampleService.ImageUpload(userid, file)
        .subscribe(photo => {
           
         ,
          err => {
           
            
          });
  }
```

in service file do like below

```
    ImageUpload(id, file) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    return this.Http.post(this.url+ 'ImageUpload' + '/' + id, formData);
  }
```

in WEB API do like below code to receive file from Angular

```
[HttpPost("ImageUpload/{Id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> plantFileUpload(string Id, [FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile file)
{

}
```

This should work

Comment: Tried that. It still has the same error. I've no idea what I'm going wrong on this.