# Nodejs Upload File to Strapi Using FormData

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data, form-data, strapi

hi im having trouble on uploading a file to strapi from backend nodejs im doing

```
bodyFormData.append('files.image', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path), req.file.filename);
bodyFormData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

and using axios to create a post request

```
axios({
        url:`${strapi}/campaigns`,
        method:'post',
        data:bodyFormData,
        withCredentials:true,
      })
      .then(response=>{
        console.log(response.data)
        // return res.status(200).send(response.data)
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        res.status(400).send(err)
      })
```

here's my console.log(bodyFormData)

```
FormData {
[0]   _overheadLength: 288,
[0]   _valueLength: 272,
[0]   _valuesToMeasure: [],
[0]   writable: false,
[0]   readable: true,
[0]   dataSize: 0,
[0]   maxDataSize: 2097152,
[0]   pauseStreams: true,
[0]   _released: false,
[0]   _streams: [
[0]     '----------------------------167862620653181372969530\r\n' +
[0]       'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files.image"; filename="1582728780533-fancy-bottom-border.png"\r\n' +
[0]       'Content-Type: image/png\r\n' +
[0]       '\r\n',
[0]     'public\\1582728780533-fancy-bottom-border.png',
[0]     [Function: bound ],
[0]     '----------------------------167862620653181372969530\r\n' +
[0]       'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"\r\n' +
[0]       '\r\n',
[0]     '{"title":"123`${strapi}/campaigns`","description":"`${strapi}/campaigns`","author":{"id":62},"reference":30939226,"goal":"123","verified":false,"deleted":false,"requested":false,"raised":0,"username":"cjoyales","currency":"USD"}',
[0]     [Function: bound ]
[0]   ],
[0]   _currentStream: null,
[0]   _insideLoop: false,
[0]   _pendingNext: false,
[0]   _boundary: '--------------------------167862620653181372969530'
[0] }
```

but here's the console.log(response.data) from strapi

```
{
[0]   id: 176,
[0]   title: '',
[0]   description: '',
[0]   goal: 0,
[0]   raised: null,
[0]   username: null,
[0]   created_at: '2020-02-26T14:53:00.000Z',
[0]   updated_at: '2020-02-26T14:53:00.000Z',
[0]   verified: null,
[0]   deleted: null,
[0]   author: null,
[0]   reference: null,
[0]   currency: null,
[0]   requested: null,
[0]   done: null,
[0]   image: [],
[0]   supporters: []
[0] }
```

why is it empty or null even there are values in the form data? can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Hello! Did you check JS examples here https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/upload.html ?

Comment: yes i already checked the documentation .. the backend received the data but when the backend sends the data to strapi via post request ... the backend recieves the empty or null values from strapi

Comment: I'm using `useStrapiClient` and it doesn't appear to support formdata objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

`bodyFormData.append('files.image', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path), req.file.filename);`

with

`bodyFormData.append('files', fs.createReadStream(req.file.path), req.file.filename);`

I struggled for hours with something similar until I read Pavlo Razumovskyi's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722625/upload-image-to-strapi/52693039):

> It's new api now, check new docs:
>   strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/…
>   formData.append('files.MODEL_FILE_FIELD_NAME', blob, filename)